# How to speedup wordpress website. take too much time to loading

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in wordpress , I build a website in wordpress , but it take too much time to load can you told what should i do to increase performance,

I already install cache plugins. but not getting to much improvement .

Comment: Please share the site url

Comment: I am woring in localhost.

Comment: Seriously? you expect somebody to come over from here to find the issue with your computer?

Comment: This is my instruction article about [speedup wordpress site](http://blog.kingcomposer.com/how-to-optimize-speed-up-for-any-wordpress-website-with-w3-total-cache/), hope help someone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install some image Compress plugins `Compress JPEG & PNG images` to optimize image and try to use Thumbnail image in your page .

I think you use full size image in you page try to use small size image.

```
//Default WordPress
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );     // Thumbnail (150 x 150 hard cropped)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );        // Medium resolution (300 x 300 max height 300px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium_large' );  // Medium Large (added in WP 4.4) resolution (768 x 0 infinite height)
the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );         // Large resolution (1024 x 1024 max height 1024px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );          // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
```

And you can put this in you `.htaccess` file to cache you js and Css and image file

```
ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
```

Comment: yes, I am using the_post_thumbnail_url() function to get image url ,i change  it with  the_post_thumbnail_url('medium')  and loding time is better then previous

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose a good host.
2. Start with a solid framework/theme.
3. Use an effective caching plugin.
4. Use a content delivery network (CDN)
5. Optimize images (automatically)
6. Optimize your homepage to load quickly.
7. Optimize your WordPress database.
8. Disable hotlinking and leeching of your content.
9. Add an expires header to static resources
10. Adjust Gravatar images
11. Add LazyLoad to your images
12. Control the amount of post revisions stored
13. Turn off pingbacks and trackbacks
14. Replace PHP with static HTML, when necessary
15. Use CloudFlare

Answer (score 0):

Test your website in google speed test tool and then follow instruction given by google for your website.

[Google Speed Test Tool](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)
: Generally tool advise for css and js minification. And you will also be instructed to optimize Images.

These all optimized content are given by google it self, after test complete. Use those content and you are good.